# Not able to get transparent QRubberband

Tags: qt

I am trying to draw a rectangle using `QRubberBand`. I need the rectangle border to be opaque and its inside to be transparent. But, I am able to do it only other way around, with the border to be transparent and its filling in opaque. Here is the code I am using,

```
class roiFrame : public QRubberBand
{
public:
    roiFrame(Shape s, QWidget * p = 0):QRubberBand(s, p){}
    ~roiFrame(){}


protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(pe);

        QStyleOptionRubberBand opt;
        QStylePainter painter(this);
        painter.setOpacity(0.8); // from aamer4yu
        opt.initFrom(this);
        //  opt.opcatiy = false; //This one also makes the border to be transparent .
        painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_FocusFrame, opt);
    }
};
```

As an alternative, I tried to draw a rectangle using `QPainter::drawRect`:

```
myWindow::myWindow(QWidget *parent): QFrame(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

myWindow::~myWindow()
{
}

void myWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    releaseX = event->x();
    releaseY = event->y();
}

void myWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    pressX = event->x();
    pressY = event->y();
}

void myWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFrame::paintEvent(event);
    QRectF rectangle(pressX,pressY,releaseX,releaseY);
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setOpacity(0.8);
    painter.drawRect(rectangle);
    painter.end();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the default `QRubberBand::paintEvent`? Or why do you not use `QStyle::CE_RubberBand` as first argument of `drawControl`?

Comment: I am not able to get the transparent rectangles using the default paintEvent so I modified them. QStyle::CE_RubberBand was also not doing the job.

I am trying to draw rectangle on video, based on mouse press event. drawRect function was also not doing the job.

Comment: Can you add what you tried with `drawRect`. As you want a very specific result, using this low level function seems appropriate to me.

Comment: hi, I have added the myWindow class, in which I have used drawRect function. myWindow class inherits QFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `drawRect` is that you do not specify how the rectangle should look like, i.e. the properties of the border and its inside:

- You can specify the border style using [`QPainter::setPen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setPen) (or one of its overloads)
- You can specify how the rectangle is filled using [`QPainter::setBrush`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setBrush) (or one of its overloads)

In your case, only the border should be drawn. So, you should use something like this:

```
painter.setPen(Qt::red);
```

**Remarks**

- Note that it may be necessary to call [`QWidget::update`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update-2) to force a repaint event.
- Note that the third and fourth constructor parameter of [`QRectF`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#QRectF-3) are the width and height and not the bottom right coordinates. As an alternative, you may use the [following constructor overload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#QRectF-2): `QRectF rectangle(QPointF(pressX,pressY),QPointF(releaseX,releaseY));`