# QT Draw Rectangle on QGraphicsitem

Tags: c++, qt

**My work Environment:** Qt 5.8 MSVC2015 64bit, QT GraphicsView, QGraphicsObject, Windows 7 64 bit.

In my application I have added multiple QGraphicsitem, into a single graphic scene & into a single graphic view.

But I need to draw empty green color rectangle on top of QGraphicsitem image, as per mouse position. 
So I tried with below :

```
QRubberBand* _rubberBand = new QRubberBand(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
_rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(MousePos.x() -2, MousePos.y() - 2, MousePos.x() + 2, MousePos.y() + 2).normalized());
_rubberBand->setAutoFillBackground(false);
QPalette pal;
pal.setBrush(QPalette::Highlight, QBrush(Qt::green));
_rubberBand->setPalette(pal);
_rubberBand->show();
```

Issue with QRubberBand, it changes size dynamically, I want draw small rectangle,   not flickery RubberBand.

**QRubberBand Output:**

[image: QRubberBand Code OutPut]

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395296/not-able-to-get-transparent-qrubberband/44418167#44418167.
Note that the question itself already contains a large part of a possible solution.

Comment: @m7913d , QPalette don't have option of setColor.  //pal.setColor();

Comment: `QPalette` has a [`setColor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setColor-1) method, but you should also specify a [`ColorRole`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum). Note that the duplicate question does not use `QPalette`, although it may be possible too.

Comment: @m7913d,  Nope, I tried with   pal.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(128,128,255));    But  it still fill up full rect with color. I need only border to be set with color.

Comment: You may need to set the brush to transparent. Nevertheless, the answer you created is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

@m7913d, tons of thanks for your value added suggestion.
I have Override QRubberBand class &  set QRubberBand class setGeometry, setPen & it's color.

Here is final solution code :

```
class roiFrame : public QRubberBand
{
public:
    roiFrame(Shape s, QWidget * p = 0):QRubberBand(s, p){}
    ~roiFrame(){}
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(pe);
        QStyleOptionRubberBand opt;
        QStylePainter painter(this);
        opt.initFrom(this);
        QRect rectangle(0,0,30, 15);
        QColor color(Qt::green);
        painter.setPen(color);
        painter.drawRect(rectangle);
    }
};
```

**Caller code :**

```
_rectFrame = new roiFrame(QRubberBand::Rectangle, this);
_rectFrame->setGeometry(QRect(thumbMousePos.x() -1, thumbMousePos.y() - 1, thumbMousePos.x() + 1, thumbMousePos.y() + 1).normalized());
_rectFrame->setAutoFillBackground(false);
_rectFrame->show();
```